# Passar variável via GET sem action

Tags: php, html

Eu pretendo passar uma variável para outra página, eu sei que posso usar o método `GET`, entretanto se aqui `<form method="GET" action="comentario.php">` estiver `comentario.php` ele não executa os comandos para inserir na base de dados (esse código encontra-se na mesma página), para inserir ficaria `<form method="GET" action="">` porém a variável obviamente já não é reconhecida na outra página, (neste caso a variável é `$lang=$_GET['lang'];`)
A minha dúvida é como eu faço de modo a que passe a variável para outra página? Já agora não estou a usar `Sessions`.
Página principal:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <table width="80%" align="center" cellpadding="8">
        <br><br>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" class="logo">
                <img src="imagens/logo.png" height="40" width="150">
            </td>
            <td class="idioma" align="right">
                <?php $lang=isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET["lang"] : false; ?>
                <select id="lang" name="lang" onchange="submitForm()">
                    <?php
                    switch ($lang) {
                        case 'en':
                        $lng=1;
                        break;
                        case 'fr':
                        $lng=2;
                        break;
                        case 'sp':
                        $lng=3;
                        break;
                        case 'de':
                        $lng=4;
                        break;
                        default:
                        $lng=0;
                    }
                    $questao=array('O que achou do nosso serviço?','ingles','frances','espanhol','alemao');

                    ?>
                    <option value="pt"<?php if($lang != 'fr' && $lang != 'en' && $lang != 'sp' && $lang != 'de'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Português</option>
                    <option value="en"<?php if($lang == 'en'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>English</option>
                    <option value="fr"<?php if($lang == 'fr'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Français</option>
                    <option value="sp"<?php if($lang == 'sp'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Español</option>
                    <option value="de"<?php if($lang == 'de'){ echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Deutsch</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="pergunta" align="center">
                <hr>
                <?php echo $questao[$lng]; ?>
                <hr>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="selecao">
                <div class="cores">
                    <input type="submit" name="verde" class="verde" value="verde">
                    <input type="submit" name="amarelo" class="amarelo" value="amarelo">
                    <input type="submit" name="vermelho" class="vermelho" value="vermelho">

                    <?php
                    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon"); //definir zona
                    $data=date("Y-m-d"); //definir data
                    $hora = date("H:i:s"); //definir hora

                    if (isset($_GET['verde'])) {
                        $classificacao=$_GET['verde'];
                    }
                    elseif (isset($_GET['amarelo'])) {
                        $classificacao=$_GET['amarelo'];
                    }
                    elseif (isset($_GET['vermelho'])) {
                        $classificacao=$_GET['vermelho'];
                    }


                    if (isset($classificacao)) {
                        $inserir=mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO questionario (pergunta_id, pergunta, data, hora, idioma, origem, classificacao) VALUES ('','".$questao[$lng]."','$data','$hora','$lang', '','$classificacao')");
                        if (!$inserir) 
                        {
                            echo "Erro ao inserir na tabela.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            header('location: comentario.php');
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Como podem ver não inseri nada no `action`, só assim ele funciona para inserir os dados na base de dados. 

A outra página que quero passar a variável `$lang=$_GET['lang'];`

```
<td colspan="3" class="pergunta" align="center">
            <hr>
            <?php $lang=isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET["lang"] : false; 
            $lang=$_GET['lang'];

            if ($lang=='pt') {
                echo "Deixe aqui o seu comentário";
            }elseif ($lang == 'en')
            {
                echo "ENGLISH";
            }elseif ($lang=='sp')
            {
                echo "espanhol";
            }elseif ($lang=='de') {
                echo "alemao";
            }elseif ($lang=='fr') {
                echo "frances";
            }
            ?>

            <hr>
        </td>
```

Se o action conter `comentario.php` (nome desta página) este código funciona, caso contrário, ele diz `Notice: Undefined index: lang in`

Comment: Ficou bem confuso. A variável em questão é `$_GET['lang']`, certo? O que seria o código de inserção? Qual a relação dele com o problema? Em que arquivo ele se encontra? O que faz o arquivo `comentario.php`? Você quer passar a variável de onde para onde e o que precisa fazer com ela?

Comment: Peço desculpa Andersion! Sim a variável em questão é essa. Vou alterar a minha questão para você dar uma vista de olhos

Comment: Substitua `header('location: comentario.php');` por `header("location: comentario.php?lang={$lang}");` e remova `$lang=$_GET['lang'];`.

Comment: Valdeir, obrigada desde já, eu tentei mas assim não aparece o texto, por exemplo se o idioma fosse português na página principal, na próxima deveria aparecer "Deixe aqui o seu comentário", simplesmente não aparece nada...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi, mas para passar valores para outras páginas você pode usar a URL, depois usa o $_RESQUEST para pegar o valor.

Exemplo:

```
você pode montar uma url no Href
<a href='comentario.php?lang=pt-br'>Acessar</a>
Url ficaria +/- assim
    http://pagina.com/comentario.php?lang=pt-br

No php você pode pegar o valor assim
    $lang= $_REQUEST["lang"];
```

Esse é um exemplo bem simples, com certeza tem outras formas

Comment: Rafa vou marcar a sua resposta como correta, porque usei o seu exemplo, obrigada! Para resolver totalmente eu utilizei por exemplo: `if ($lang != 'fr' && $lang != 'en' && $lang != 'sp' && $lang != 'de') {
         header('location: comentario.php?lang=pt');
        }elseif ($lang == 'en') {
         header('location: comentario.php?lang=en');
         
        }` etc

Comment: Show de bola. Fico feliz por ter ajudado.